# Запись массива в базу данных с использованием FMDatabase

Tags: sqlite3, массивы, sqlite, ios, база-данных

Как красиво реализовать запись массива данных в базу SQLite с использованием библиотеки FMDatabase? решение без использования библиотек нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342067/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-sqlite-database)

```
//псевдокод
[db beginTransaction];
        // запись элементов в базу в цикле for    
[db endTransaction];
```

Comment: А чем не устроил стандартный CoreData?

Comment: @Bimawa, при больших нагрузках у Core Data проявляются недостатки которые могут стать ключевыми

Comment: @AlexThumb, это что -то типо приложения для работы с биржей? Или база фсб?

Comment: @Bimawa, не понял Вашей шутки. Чтобы не оффтопить, создайте отдельно вопрос, там подискутируем.

Comment: приложение отображает данные аналогично новостной стене в контакте, от библиотеки не можем отказаться, так как она уже используется в проекте, который я переписываю

Comment: > @Bimawa, при больших нагрузках у Core Data проявляются недостатки которые могут стать ключевыми

@AlexThumb, очень интересно, чтобы вы описали, о каких именно недостатках идёт речь. Желательно, со ссылками на чёткие источники и/или тесты производительности.

@АлексейАлыбин, к сожалению с FMDatabase я не работал, подсказать не смогу, поэтому просто спрошу: чем, действительно, вас не устроил стандартный Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[DB sharedDB].queue  inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    NSException *exception = [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"Database insert error" reason:@"Can not insert data into database in transaction" userInfo:nil];
    [db beginTransaction];
    @try
    {
        for (APIServiceItem *item in items) {
            NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO content (uid, title, content) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@')", item.uid, item.title, item.content];
            BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:query];

            if (!success) {
                @throw exception;
            }
        }

        [db commit];
    }
    @catch(NSException* e) {
        [db rollback];
    }

}];
```